# Sample arbitrary amount of numbers from Haskell list

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to learn Haskell from a Ruby background. I'm looking to be able to get an arbitrary number of items from a list:

```
sample [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
=> 7
sample 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
=> [4,2,9]
```

This is available in Ruby and I'm hoping to get the same functionality. I haven't been able to find it after some googling, so I figured I would ask here. Is this available or is it a function I would have to implement myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html for sample, which chooses n random indices into the array, I came up with the following:

```
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Control.Applicative

sample1 xs = do
  let l = length xs - 1
  idx <- randomRIO (0, l)
  return $ xs !! idx

sample 0 xs = return []
sample n xs = do
  let l = min n (length xs)
  val <- sample1 xs
  (:) <$> (pure val) <*> (sample (l-1) (delete val xs))
```

Alternatively, you could use `Control.Monad` instead of `Control.Applicative` and `liftM2 (:) (return val) (sample (ct-1) (delete val xs))`

Using `delete` does incur an `Eq` constraint on the type of the list elements, though, so you would have to split/merge at the index if you needed to avoid that.

Comment: that's great, works just how I want. I'm somewhat new, so could you explain the last line in the sample n method? Also, why do you do `idx <- randomRIO (0, l)` instead of `let idx = ...`?

Comment: it looks like it is recursively calling sample on the list that just had the last selected value deleted? and once it gets down to zero it returns the empty list `[]`, ending the process.

Comment: Use let when binding a pure value as a result of a function returning pure values. Use <- when binding the pure value as a result of a monadic computation.

Comment: Recall that do is syntactic sugar for `=<<`, where the right side of a `=<<` expression is a function that is given one value. In this case, the last two lines would de-sugar to something like `(sample1 xs) =<< (\val -> (:) <$> (pure val) <*> (sample l-1) (delete val xs)))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `random.shuffle` package, which comes with a [`shuffle'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-shuffle/0.0.4/doc/html/System-Random-Shuffle.html) function. But you need a Random generator.

You can also look for further explanation on the haskell wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle

Once your list is shuffled, you can `take n` elements of it.

Comment: don't use the `shuffle` function. the work of actually generating the list of randoms is done by `shuffleM` (or `shuffle'`) probably better than you could do by yourself.

Comment: I was actually thinking of `shuffle'`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import System.Random

sample :: Int -> [a] -> IO [a]
sample count lst = go count lst []
   where go 0 _ acc = return acc
         go count xs acc = do
            rnd <- randomIO :: IO Int
            let ind = rnd `rem` (length xs)
                (beg, (r:rs)) = splitAt ind xs
            go (count-1) (beg ++ rs) (r : acc)
```

Since random number generation is impure you need to be in the IO monad, although you could generate a random seed and then pas that to the function.  This code gets a random int, makes sure it is inside the bounds of the list.  Then splits the list and returns that number thus removing it from the list and then recursing until no more numbers are needed.

Comment: He could also use one of the random-specific monads such as `Rand` from MonadRandom (a specialization of `State`).

Comment: well, if it were rewritten to `getRandom` instead of randomIO. `getRandomR (0, length xs-1)`?

Comment: @sreservoir: There's actually a `randomRIO` too, so the functions are very similar.  For the IO case, the code would be something like `sample xs = (map (xs!!) . take len) \`fmap\` replicateM len randomRIO where len = length xs`

Comment: they are, but I think I'd rather have a `sample :: MonadRandom m => Int -> [a] -> m [a]` instead of explicitly different IO and generator cases. that *might* just be me, of course.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Your example doesn't compile.  You don't include a range for `randomRIO` and even if it did you could still have repeat indices.

Comment: True, good thing it's just a comment.  Also, I didn't see if this was sampling with or without replacement in the original question.